# How to create a response with $ref and add extra properties in OpenAPI 3?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have created a `patient` component and using it as a response like this.

```yaml
          description: Success get all patients
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/InventoryItem'
```

However the response only contains the patient data but I want to add extra properties to my response like this

```json
{
  code: 200,
  message: "Success get all patients data"
  data: [
    // Patient data
  ]
}
```

What is the syntax to achieve the above response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `properties` and just add the extra properties like this.

```
description: Success get all patients
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  status:
                    type: number
                    example: 200
                  message:
                    type: string
                    example: Success get all patients
                  data:
                    type: array
                    items: 
                      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Patient'
```

And your response will be

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "message": "Success get all patients",
  "data": [
    {
      // The data
    }
  ]
}
```